# Upload Multiple Image to php Server from android using Loopj framework?

Tags: java, android

When uploaded image from android to php server, the image is detected as text parameter. Please help me. I am sending  UserId and Description along with image Request Params. Image Uploading to server is using Post Method.

Comment: whats loopj framework?

Comment: loopj is a framework used to JsonResponse from Server. Instagram uses Loopj to get Response.

Comment: ok but sending of image to php is also incude loopj?

Comment: I don't know about LoopJ.
I used this in my project https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service and is perfect.